# Very slow TCP handshake in Java application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tcp, aix, apache-mina

Our Java application consists of a client and a server. In our production environment, establishing the connection takes a long time (~40 seconds).

We captured the network traffic using tcpdump and can see the following packets when the connection is established:

```
start                  client > server SYN
2 milliseconds later   server < client SYN,ACK
38 *seconds* later     client > server ACK
```

In our other environments, all three packets occur nearly instantaneously.

Can anyone suggest what might cause the 38 second delay, or suggest steps to diagnose it? Note that, because this is a production environment, it's hard for us to make diagnostic code changes.

Here are some details about our environment:

- The client uses SocketConnector from [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/) 1.0.1, which internally uses java.nio.channel.SocketChannel.connect(..).
- The client is running inside IBM WebSphere 7.0.0.17
- Java version = 1.6.0, Java Compiler = j9jit24, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
- OS is AIX, version 6.1

Comment: Is the tcpdump from the client or server?

Comment: I *think* the tcpdump is from the client (unfortunately it was not captured by me).

Comment: Then the slowness is from the client. You might want to read up on what's happening on the AIX stack between the SYNC-ACK and the ACK.

Answer (score 1):

aren't you running out of descriptor and/or your TCP accept queue is full ?

Comment: Are you referring to the client side or the server side? The reason I ask is that I'd assume the accept queue is only relevant on the server side, and I don't think that's where the delay is occurring.